# How to prove that $(a^b)^c = a^{(bc)}$ for rational and negative exponents?

Tags: exponentiation, rational-numbers

I have this question about exponentiation.
How can one prove that $(a^b)^c$ = $a^{(bc)}$ for rational and negative exponents?

Firstly, we need a basis of what a rational and negative exponent are.

So, for these purposes, I define rational exponentiation, for a number to the power of the fraction $\frac mn$, so $a^{\frac mn}$ as being $(\sqrt[n]a)^m$ and a negative exponent $a^{(-x)}$ as being $\frac 1a^x$.

How can one prove that these hold? Also, how can one prove that this holds for any number of exponents (e.g. $((a^b)^c)^d$ = $a^{(bcd)}$?

Also, how can one prove this holds for "mixed" exponents, like
$(a^3)^\frac 23$, or $(a^3)^{-2}$?

Thank you. I'm aware I posted this prior, but the post was of very low quality, I didn't define either and I felt as if it was best to rewrite it, and make it clear.

Comment: Prove it first for positive integer exponents. Then prove it for exponents that can have negative signs but are still integral. To prove it for rational exponents, use the fact that $a^{p/q}$ is the unique real number $r$ such that $r^q = a^p$ and use the result for integer exponents.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin For rational exponents, you also need to show that your definition is in fact well-defined; in other words, that if $\frac pq= \frac rs$, then $a^{\frac pq}=a^{\frac rs}$.  This is true, of course, but it does require proof.

Comment: Morally, I think the right way of doing this is arguing that these properties hold for $x \mapsto \exp(\lambda x)$, defined analytically e.g., via a power series, and then arguing that this map specializes to rational exponentiation for appropriate $x, \lambda$.